# Seleccionar registro con menor hora de cada dia - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

SQL SERVER 2012

Tengo una vista llamada `Vw_Articulos_Stock_Manual_Rep` con los campos:

```
Id_Art_Stock_Manual, 
Descripcion(Tbl_Articulos), 
Nombre_Sucursal(Tbl_Sucursal), 
Stock_Manual, 
Fecha_Stock_Manual(Datetime), 
Hora_Stock_Manual(Varchar(5))
```

Hay múltiples artículos y sucursales.

Este es el codigo que uso para 1 fecha, 1 sucursal y 1 articulo determinado:

```
SELECT Descripcion, Nombre_Sucursal, Stock_Manual, Fecha_Stock_Manual, MIN(Hora_Stock_Manual) 
FROM CENTRAL.dbo.Vw_Articulos_Stock_Manual_Rep 
WHERE CONVERT(Date, Fecha_Stock_Manual) = '01/02/2020'
AND Id_Art = 147 AND Id_Sucursal = 5
GROUP BY  Descripcion, Nombre_Sucursal, Stock_Manual, Fecha_Stock_Manual
ORDER BY Fecha_Stock_Manual
```

En un mismo dia pueden haber registros con el mismo articulo, misma sucursal y misma fecha pero con diferente cantidad de stock y en diferentes horarios.

[image]

Lo que necesito es que me de el registro con la menor hora para cada dia, para cada artículo y para cada sucursal. Sin tener que aclararle que sucursal y que articulo es (Que lo haga para todos los articulos en cada una de las sucursales).

Lo que quiero lograr es ver con que stock abre una sucursal con un articulo determinado.

Comment: bueno la formulo de vuelta para que veas bien lo que quiero hacer. hago un ejemplo con una sucursal y articulo determinado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok.. aca tenemos que hacer dos cosas.. primero separar la fecha de la hora (no sirve como esta ahora) y despues hacer las agrupaciones.

Para solo la fecha, tenemos ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/113045/73749)) :

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, getdate())
```

Y para obtener solo la hora de una fecha tenemos ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7710449/73749))

```
cast(AttDate as time)
```

Asi que ahora a tu query hay que transformarlo un poco:

```
SELECT Descripcion,     
    Nombre_Sucursal, 
    CONVERT(date, Fecha_Stock_Manual) Fecha, 
    MIN(cast(Hora_Stock_Manual as time)) Hora
FROM CENTRAL.dbo.Vw_Articulos_Stock_Manual_Rep 
WHERE CONVERT(Date, Fecha_Stock_Manual) = '01/02/2020'
    AND Id_Art = 147 AND Id_Sucursal = 5
GROUP BY  Descripcion, Nombre_Sucursal, CONVERT(date, Fecha_Stock_Manual)
ORDER BY MIN(cast(Hora_Stock_Manual as time))
```

Ahora, una vez que sabemos que articulo, descripcion y la menor fecha, lo unimos a la misma tabla para traer el stock de ese registro:

```
select b.*, a.Stock_Manual
from CENTRAL.dbo.Vw_Articulos_Stock_Manual_Rep  as a inner join (
    SELECT Descripcion,     
        Nombre_Sucursal, 
        CONVERT(date, Fecha_Stock_Manual) Fecha, 
        MIN(cast(Hora_Stock_Manual as time)) Hora
    FROM CENTRAL.dbo.Vw_Articulos_Stock_Manual_Rep 
    WHERE CONVERT(Date, Fecha_Stock_Manual) = '01/02/2020'
        AND Id_Art = 147 AND Id_Sucursal = 5
    GROUP BY  Descripcion, Nombre_Sucursal, CONVERT(date, Fecha_Stock_Manual)) as b 
on a.Descripcion= b.Descripcion 
    and a.Nombre_Sucursal= b.Nombre_Sucursal 
    and CONVERT(date, a.Fecha_Stock_Manual)=b.fecha
    and cast(a.Hora_Stock_Manual as time)=b.Hora
```

Comment: Va mejorando pero todavia no devuelve lo correcto. Con esa consulta me devuelve 3 registros para el mismo dia con las horas 8 am, 16 pm y 20 pm que justo son los registros que tienen diferente cantidad de stock.

Comment: Con mi consulta me devolvia 5 registros: 8 am (stock 5), 11 am (stock 5), 16 pm (stock 4), 20 pm (stock 7)

Comment: Ah perdon. No tenes que agrupar por stock entonces. Que queres hacer con el stock?

Comment: Necesito mostrar la cantidad de stock que hay para cada dia, articulo y sucursal. Pero solo del registro con menor hora (es para saber con que stock abre una sucursal con un articulo determinado)

Comment: Probe con sacarle el select y group by de stock y me da lo que quiero. Pero como hago para seleccionar la cantidad de stock sin tener que agruparla?

Comment: No se si esto sera de ayuda pero yo a esta consulta la paso a VB.Net para poder generar un reporte en crystal reports en el cual ya aclare el origen de los datos y las tablas que muestro.

Comment: Esta query tiene que ser la entrada de otra query que traiga el stock... ahora lo arreglo

Comment: Buenisimo, muchas gracias por tomarte tu tiempo. Estuve 2 dias tratando de arreglar esto. Espero tu query

Comment: Si estuviste 2 dias para esto, es importante que aprendas sql. esto no es complicado ni requiere saber mucho de sql.

Comment: Si si en eso estoy. Solo tengo mi conocimiento que adquiri en la universidad y funciones como CAST nunca las habiamos visto. Son mis primeros meses trabajando en el rubro asique muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Listo @Juan revisalo ahora

Comment: Me salta este error: La cláusula ORDER BY no es válida en vistas, funciones insertadas, tablas derivadas, subconsultas ni expresiones de tabla común, salvo que se especifique también TOP, OFFSET o FOR XML.

Comment: Y si saco la clausula order by me devuelve los 5 registros que me devolvia con mi primer consulta pero todos con la misma hora que es la menor de los 5

Comment: ok.. el order no va.. y falto una clausula en el join.. por eso te trae mas registros...

Comment: LEFT, RIGHT o alguna de esas? porque probe con esas dos y tampoco dá. Disculpa si mis preguntas son muy basicas pero recien estoy empezando con esto

Comment: ya la agregue.. sin importar si sos novato o no, entendes lo que escribi en la consulta y cual es la idea?

Comment: Claro ! Unes la consulta que trae el stock con la que necesito yo. Muchas gracias no sabia que se podia hacer un join de ese tipo. Todos los dias se aprende algo nuevo